# How to hide options in the second select before choosing option in first select

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, entities

i have taxonomy : Cities and taxonomy Towns.

- cities have : Sousse and Tunis
- Town have Elzahra (related to Tunis (taxonomy cities) and Sahlool (realted to Sousse (taxonomy cities)).

i have installed the module "reference_option_limit" and i created in the content a field named city and an other field named Town , in Town field i have coched : 
[image]
and i created a view for this content : 
[image]
but the problem in the page it shows me all the options: for the second select:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, you want to show in the second filter only the towns (villages) related to the selected city (ville) in the first filter. That means, the content of the second filter depends on the selection in the first filter. Am I right?

In that case, you might try something like the [Views Dependent Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_dependent_filters) module. See below its description:

> Suppose you had a view showing several kinds of products, such as
>   cake, bicycles, and books, and an exposed filter on product type that
>   lets the user refine the listing to one or more types.
>
> With this module you could add the following filters:
>
> ```
> cake flavour, such as lemon, chocolate, coffee
> bicycle size
> book genre
> ```
>
> Each filter will only show when the type it relates to is selected in
>   the filter for product type.

Comment: yes you are right, ok wait i will try this module now

Comment: yes it works but I want that the second field "dependent" is always displayed at the beginning but it takes the value <-any-> !! ?